# Curve length of intersection between plane and cylinder

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I'm looking to find $\int\limits_{C} x ds$ (curve length) along the first octant part of the curve intersection of the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=a^{2}$ and the plane $z=x$. I will summarize below what I have done so far, but I have been unable to put all the information together to find the correct solution.

What I think I should do is first parametrize the equation for the cylinder into the following:

${\bf r} = a\cos(t){\bf i} + a\sin(t){\bf j}+z{\bf k}$.

Then $\frac{dr}{dt} = -a\sin(t){\bf i} + a\cos(t){\bf j}$ and the absolute value would be $a$.

Hence I think the curve length should be given by $\int a\sin(t) \times a \, dt$.

However, after this I am lost. I know because of the plane $x=z$ that the curve will stop when $z=x=a^{2}$ so that is a limit, and another limit will be given by the fact that this curve is in the first octant so $ 0 \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $.

Comment: The cylinder section is an ellipse and the arc length involves elliptic integral.

Comment: @NgChungTak thank you, but I haven't covered this yet, so I think there should be a (maybe longer) solution given the observations I have written in the question.

Comment: Your question is contradictory. You are asking for the length of the curve but write $\int\limits_{C} x ds$, which is something different. As this integral has an easy analytical solution, I'd be tempted to believe that this is the real question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was not aware that my notation was contradictory, but indeed I'm asking for the line integral/curve length

Comment: @LunaStar: line integral or curve length ? Same ambiguity.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh ok, I was under the impression that they were equivalent. But it is an integral with a c, so I think then its a line integral.

Comment: @LunaStar: no, the confusion is between $ds$ and $x\,ds$.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is? Because I was indeed prompted with $\int\limits_{C} x ds$  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  x^2+y^2 &= a^2 \\
  x &= z \\
  \mathbf{r}(t) &= (a\cos t,a\sin t,a\cos t) \\
  \mathbf{r}'(t) &= (-a\sin t,a\cos t,-a\sin t) \\
  ds &= |\mathbf{r}'(t)|\, dt \\
     &= a\sqrt{2\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t} \, dt \\
     &= a\sqrt{2-\cos^2 t} \, dt \\
  s &= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} a\sqrt{2-\cos^2 t}\, dt \\
    &= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} a\sqrt{2-\sin^2 t}\, dt \\
    &= a\sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 t}\, dt \\
    &= a\sqrt{2} E\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Good answer, but possibly to the wrong question.